# How to use Join operation/ Subquery in CosmosDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a container in CosmosDB. It contains around 30 variables. CabId is one of the column/variable in that. I want to select duplicate values of CabId and delete those items completely for duplicate CabIds. PartitionKey is another variable in my item.
One item will look like below.

```json
{
     "CabId": "8dc2d0f4-d787-4e98-94d0-665a69bfbbf5",
     "OS_FlightRing": "*****",
     "CPU_FamilyName": "*****",
     "Incident_FailureBucketId": "*****",
     "Geo_ISOCountryShortCode": "cn",
     "OS_Version": "10.0.19042.985",
     "PartitionKey": "29997810-1199392862021-10-20"
}
```

I am using query like this for getting the individual items with duplicate CabId. But I am getting syntax error.

```sql
Select * from e JOIN(
 SELECT * FROM( 
  (SELECT c.CabId,Count(c.CabId) AS CabCount
   FROM c
   where c.PartitionKey = "29997810-1238691972021-10-25"
   GROUP BY c.CabId)
 d WHERE d.CabCount > 1))
on d.CabId = e.CabId
```

Answer (score 0):

The below query should give you the duplicates,

```
Select d.CabId From
(SELECT c.CabId,Count(c.CabId) AS 
CabCount FROM c GROUP BY c.CabId) AS d WHERE d.CabCount > 1
```

> {
> "CabId": "8dc2d6f4-d787-4e98-94d0-665a69bfbbf5",
> "OS_FlightRing": "",
> "CPU_FamilyName": "",
> "Incident_FailureBucketId": "*****",
> "Geo_ISOCountryShortCode": "cn",
> "OS_Version": "10.0.19042.985",
> "PartitionKey": "29597810-1199392862021-10-20",
> "id": "703f5337-4fc2-4d77-acc9-2fbf15900366",
> "_rid": "uYFGAPqp2KYCAAAAAAAAAA==",
> "_self": "dbs/uYFGAA==/colls/uYFGAPqp2KY=/docs/uYFGAPqp2KYCAAAAAAAAAA==/",
> "_etag": ""8c00d214-0000-0700-0000-6172ba160000"",
> "_attachments": "attachments/",
> "_ts": 1634908694 }

**UPDATE:**

```
SELECT count(1) FROM
(SELECT c.CabId ,Count(c.CabId) AS CabCount
FROM c GROUP BY c.CabId,c.PartitionKey) d WHERE d.CabCount > 1
```

Comment: Thanks @Sajeetharan for the query. I was able to run the query and get the duplicate CabIds. But my final output should give me all the output columns/variable output of an Item. For eg, Suppose CabId "123445" is duplicate value then I need to get all the columns/variable for CabId "123445", like {CabId : "123445", "OS_FlightRing": "", "CPU_FamilyName": "", "Incident_FailureBucketId": "*****", "Geo_ISOCountryShortCode": "cn", "OS_Version": "10.0.19042.985", "PartitionKey": "29997810-1199392862021-10-20", . . . . .} like that.